# Ошибка при отправке почты

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, mailkit

Всем привет. Пишу приложение на ASP.NET Core. Использую MailKit для отправки почты.
Проблема такова: невозможно подключиться к SMTP серверу (причину так и не понял).
Решил использовать SSL. Код:

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Administration", "test@mail.ru"));
            emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(email));
            emailMessage.Subject = subject;
            emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
            {
                Text = message
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.mail.ru", 25, false);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync("test@mail.ru", "*****");
                await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);

                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при отправке почты" + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ошибка:
*An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.
One possibility is that you are trying to connect to a port which does not support SSL/TLS.
The other possibility is that the SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following reasons:
The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified.
The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.
The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.
See https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate for possible solutions.*

*Произошла ошибка при попытке установить соединение SSL или TLS.
Возможно, вы пытаетесь подключиться к порту, который не поддерживает SSL / TLS.
Другая возможность состоит в том, что сертификат SSL, представленный сервером, не является доверенным для системы по одной или нескольким из следующих причин:
Сервер использует самозаверяющий сертификат, который невозможно проверить.
В локальной системе отсутствует корневой или промежуточный сертификат, необходимый для проверки сертификата сервера.
Срок действия сертификата, предоставленного сервером, истек или недействителен.
См.  для возможных решений.*

Смотрел по ссылке. Решение не помогло.
Решил сделать так, как описано здесь: [Подтверждение Email в ASP.NET Identity](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/16.5.php)

Не помогло.

И что более странно, то, что пару раз письмо отправлялось, но позже перестало.
Пробовал указать другие порты, не помогло. Я так и не понял, в чем дело.

Буду рад слышать ваши ответы.

Comment: `One possibility is that you are trying to connect to a port which does not support SSL/TLS.` там точно [должен быть 25 порт](https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/mailer/popsmtp)?

Comment: tym32167, я указывал все порты, не срабатывало.

Comment: хэлп не пробовали почитать, там указаны нужные порты: https://help.mail.ru/biz/domain/faq/clients

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой код отправки у меня когда то работал, это его копипаста, так как проверить сейчас его мне не на чем.

```
using(var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25))
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***@mail.ru", "*****");
    client.EnableSsl = true;    
    var message = new MailMessage("***@mail.ru", "email@to.com", args[0], args[1]);  
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    client.Send(message);   
}
```

Взял вашу версию программы, отправил себе несколько писем на mail.ru и на gmail.com, все работает идеально.

```
class EmailSender
{
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Administration", "*****@mail.ru"));
            emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(email));
            emailMessage.Subject = subject;
            emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
            {
                Text = message
            };

            using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
                await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.mail.ru", 25, false);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync("*****@mail.ru", "**********");
                await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);

                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при отправке почты" + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Некоторые свойства отсутствуют. Но этот код - то же самое, что и я писал. Поэтому, не думаю, что сработает.

Comment: @General2001 ну, это 100% работало дет 5 назад на обычном фрейиворке :) Я сейчас его испытать не могу, если у вас есть такая возможность - попробуйте его. Ну, и, `await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.mail.ru", 25, false);` если последний параметр про SSL, то он наверное должен быть true

Comment: tym32167, спасибо вам большое за помощь. Вы единственный человек здесь, который откликается на мои сообщения. За что респект. Но я и это тоже пробовал. Практически все варианты. Даже почту менял. И никак не срабатывает. Письмо сначала не отправлялось, позже отправилось пару раз. Затем снова перестало. Что меня удивляет, так это то, что успешное подключение все-таки было. Но! Ошибка снова появляется.

Comment: @General2001 Если вам хотя бы 1 раз удалось отправить емейл, значит, какая то из ваших папыток была успешной - то есть у вас была правильная версия кода, которая вам нужна

Comment: В этом все и дело. Я и сам не могу понять, что в моем коде может быть неправильно. Непонятно одно, если один раз отправилось, а затем перестало, в чем может быть дело? Почему-то у меня всегда возникают такие ошибки. Стоит мне с чего-нибудь начать, так я сразу получаю кучу подводных камней. И сразу складывается впечатление, что нуб...

Comment: И, кстати, я зафиксировал успешную попытку кода. Но успешная отправка произошла только 2 раза, после перестала.

Comment: @General2001 Подводные камни - это обычное дело, привыкайте. Отправка может прекратиться по миллиону причин, например, ваш провайдер, или сервер почты может посчитать вс спамером.

Comment: А возможно ли обойти это? У меня была вероятность, что меня могут посчитать спамером. Сорри, если глупый вопрос...

Comment: @General2001 учитывая, что я почту крайний раз отправлял 5 лет назад, я вам наврял ли смогу подсказать про это :)

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @General2001 обновил ответ