# Ошибка в отправке сообщение через SMTP (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, веб-программирование, обработка-ошибок, протоколы

Привет уважаемые пользователи форума. На днях столкнулся с проблемой которую я к сожалению не смог решить.
А именно: Пытаясь создать программу которая будет слать почтовые сообщение с помощью протокола **SMPT** с помощью языка (Простите меня за мою ТАВТОЛОГИЮ) программирования c#.
Вот код с ошибками

```
MailAddress From = new MailAddress("Адресс откуда", "Имя");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("Адресс куда");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(From, to);
        message.Subject = "Текстовое письма";
        message.Body = "<h4>Привет тебе гуру</h4>";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.ru", 587); //465
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Откуда", "пароль");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(message);
        MessageBox.Show("Готово");
```

Ошибки следующие:
1.Приложение на долго зависает «smtp.Send(message)» и появляется исключение System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: "The operation has timed out."
2.Или "Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first. 1651172816-FufRILun4N-6uNOUvFO" если я пишу любой другой порт отличающиеся от «465» (Хотя на форумах в не зависимости от адрес почтового сервера — smtp.yandex.ru, у этих парней все получается)
3.System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: "Failure sending mail.".

**Я перепробовал рекомендации из этой статьи:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так же пробовал другие почтовые сервера. Все аналогично.
**Отключал антивирусы и брандмауэр.**
Особенности системы: 11 Windows и 2019 VS

Буду благодарен любому совету/помощи от вас...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940987/179763 ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5D+smtp ?